# Synonymize [negative] to point to [negation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Should the [negative](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative) tag be made a synonym of the [negation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negation) master tag?
[negative](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative) has 33 questions, and [negation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negation) has 118 questions.

[double-negation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-negation) has 5 questions.  Currently there is not a [double-negative](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-negative) tag.

Comment: While these *could* be defended as different concepts, I don't think the distinction is worth preserving. It's too subtle to be useful to most learners, or even many experts. Tags should be used on many questions, not just a few. (But not too many either, like [grammar].)

Comment: *Negative* is a bad tag name anyway.  We should rename any tag that has the form of an adjective phrase or concrete noun without a plural affix.  Of course, we need to get rid of half the tags on the site . . .

Comment: By the way, we shouldn't really have a [tag:double-negation] tag.  It doesn't make sense.  The relevant technical terms are "multiple negation" and "negative concord", which are more accurate and less misleading than the "double negative".  I suppose I should start a separate thread suggesting we rename [tag:double-negation] to [tag:multiple-negation].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can't see any distinction to be made here, and as I said in my comment, I prefer [negation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negation).

At any rate, no one's voiced any objections to this proposal in the last year, so I'm going to go ahead and synonymize them.